# Starting Genymotion returns 'Segmentation fault' error

Tags: segmentation-fault, ubuntu-16.04, genymotion

Using Ubuntu 16.04.2, kernel 4.4.0-89, lxde as DE.
Downloaded genymotion v.2.10.0, trying to start, getting error:

```
root@ns337147:/opt/genymobile/genymotion# ./genymotion
Segmentation fault
```

Backtrace doesn't really make sense to me:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffea130059 in ?? () from /opt/genymobile/genymotion/platforms/libqxcb.so
#1  0x00007fffea13029b in ?? () from /opt/genymobile/genymotion/platforms/libqxcb.so
#2  0x00007fffea117d17 in ?? () from /opt/genymobile/genymotion/platforms/libqxcb.so
#3  0x00007fffea11b654 in ?? () from /opt/genymobile/genymotion/platforms/libqxcb.so
#4  0x00007fffea13034b in ?? () from /opt/genymobile/genymotion/platforms/libqxcb.so
#5  0x00007ffff7365362 in QPlatformIntegrationFactory::create(QString const&, QStringList const&, int&, char**, QString const&) () from /opt/genymobile/genymotion/libQt5Gui.so.5
#6  0x00007ffff73712e1 in QGuiApplicationPrivate::createPlatformIntegration() ()
   from /opt/genymobile/genymotion/libQt5Gui.so.5
#7  0x00007ffff737214d in QGuiApplicationPrivate::createEventDispatcher() () from /opt/genymobile/genymotion/libQt5Gui.so.5
#8  0x00007ffff702ec0f in QCoreApplication::init() () from /opt/genymobile/genymotion/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007ffff702ec76 in QCoreApplication::QCoreApplication(QCoreApplicationPrivate&) ()
   from /opt/genymobile/genymotion/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x00007ffff7374579 in QGuiApplication::QGuiApplication(QGuiApplicationPrivate&) ()
   from /opt/genymobile/genymotion/libQt5Gui.so.5
#11 0x00007ffff68002fd in QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int) ()
   from /opt/genymobile/genymotion/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#12 0x0000000000438013 in ?? ()
#13 0x0000000000422def in ?? ()
#14 0x00007ffff5d18830 in __libc_start_main (main=0x422b10, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe348, init=<optimized out>, 
    fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe338) at ../csu/libc-start.c:291
#15 0x0000000000428ad9 in ?? ()
```

All needed libraries are seem to be installed.
If any additional information is required I'll provide.

Please, help!

Comment: That looks odd indeed. Is the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable defined? If so, does it help if you unset it?

Comment: Environment variable isn't defined. Just to make sure I've unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH, no luck.

Comment: Can you paste the latest lines of ~/.Genymobile/genymotion.log ?

Comment: There's none. Tried installing genymotion on another machine and everything is fine. No idea what could be wrong - OS or hardware issue.

Comment: Could also be something with your user environment. Can you try creating a new user to see if it fails the same way?